# search for directory name not containing file with pattern

Tags: grep, find

In big list of recursive directory i am searching for directory name that does not contain a file with pattern ending with pattern "mt"

how can i search for directory name in this case .

I search net and found command to find directory name containing file with f :

```
find . -type f -name '*f*' | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' | sort | uniq
```

But how can i search for directory name w/o mt

find command but didn't found right argument

i am able to search for file name in recursive directory but here i am interested in searching for directory name in recursive pattern that does not contain a file containing a pattern with mt

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
find . -type f -name '*f*' | grep -v  'mt$'
```

`grep -v` filters out every match to the pattern that follows.

Answer (score 0):

### directory tree

```
∮ tree -F
.
├── a/
│   └── x.mt
├── b/
│   ├── x/
│   ├── y/
│   │   └── x.mt
│   └── z/
├── blacklist
└── c/
```

### create blacklist

```
∮ find . -name '*mt' | sed 's@/[^/]*mt$@@; s@^@^@' > blacklist

∮ cat blacklist
^./b/y
^./a
```

### find directories

```
∮ find . -type d | grep -v -f blacklist
.
./b
./b/x
./b/z
./c
```

---

This solution ignores all directories which directly contain `*mt` file.
It's easy to write a script (using `fgrep`) to ignore those (`.`, `./b`) which indirectly contain `*mt` file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
find -type d -exec bash -c \
'
shopt -s nullglob dotglob; 
found=; 
for f in "{}"/*mt; do 
  [[ -f $f ]] && found=true && break; 
done; 
[[ $found == true ]] || echo "{}";
' \;
```

*Change `||` to `&&` if you instead want directories that do contain `*mt`*

Might be an easier way to do this, but you can't delay glob expansion in `-exec` without `eval` (using which would cause security issues), so couldn't think of a better way then putting it into `bash -c`.